# Lagrange's Multiplier for $f(x,y,z) = (xyz)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier

Given a function:

$$f(x,y,z) = (xyz)^2$$

And the set: $$S = \{(x,y,z) : x^2 + y^2 + z^2  = a^2\} $$

Does $f$ have a maxima on $S$?

(Is this argument correct? : Yes, because f has a maxima and minima in S if S is compact and f is continuous. But here S is compact so we have a maxima)

Also, how do I tell if a function has maxima or minima on a set if the set is not compact?

I tried using the lagrange multiplier.

$f_x = 2xy^2z^2$, $f_y = 2yx^2z^2$,  $f_z = 2zx^2y^2$, $f_\lambda = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a^2$

$$f_x + \lambda g_x = 0$$
$$f_y + \lambda g_y = 0$$
$$f_z + \lambda g_z = 0$$
$$f_\lambda = 0$$

However on solving this system of equations using substitution, I am unable to find a solution for (x,y,z). I did find one point though (0,0,0), for $a = 0$,  Can I set $a$ to be $0$?

$$2xy^2z^2 = \lambda2x$$
$$2yx^2z^2 = \lambda2y$$
$$2zx^2y^2 = \lambda2z$$

So suppose $x = 0$ and $\lambda \not = 0$, we have $\lambda2y = 0$, so $y = 0$, similarly $z = 0$, $(0,0,0)$ satisfies $f_\lambda = 0$ for $a = 0$, so this is one point.

However, evaluating for other points, I am unable to simplify.

For $x \not = 0$, we have: $y^2z^2 = \lambda$

But how do I proceed from now?

Can I say by symmetry, if any one of $x$, $y$ or $z$ is $0$ then they all have to be $0$?

If so, then we have all non zero :

$$x^2z^2 = x^2y^2 = y^2z^2$$

which means $$ x^2 = y^2 = z^2$$

And then substituting this into constraint, we get 6 points of the form

$$( \pm\ a/\sqrt3, \pm\ a/\sqrt3, \pm\ a/\sqrt3)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Why do you say $S$ is unbounded?

Comment: Beware: $S$  is bounded!

Comment: What do you mean by increasing function in $\mathbb{R^3}$?  and $S$ is compact because it is bounded and contains all of its boundary points.

Comment: Oh my bad, I have made the changes. Please suggest on how to simplify. 
@J.W.Tanner

Comment: @janmarqz I have modified

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Yes, that makes sense. Thank you, I made a dumb mistake. Can you please verify if my solution is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define : $\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) = (xyz)^2 - \lambda\cdot(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a^2)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ , and for any $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ .

So, $~\mathcal{L}_x = 2xy^2z^2 - 2\lambda x~$ , $~\mathcal{L}_x = 2x^2yz^2 - 2\lambda y~$ , and $~\mathcal{L}_x = 2x^2y^2z - 2\lambda z~$ . Also, we have : $~\mathcal{L}_\lambda = a^2 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)~$ .

Equating these to $0$ , we get : $\lambda = x^2y^2 = y^2z^2 = z^2x^2~$ , and $~~a^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ .

Now, if any of $x, y, z$ is $0$ , then $f$ won't be maximized for sure, in fact it'll get minimized then. So , multiplying the first $3$ constraints by $z^2, x^2 , y^2$ respectively , we get $\lambda x^2 = \lambda y^2 = \lambda z^2$ , which implies that $f$ is maximized when $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = k~$ (Say) .

Thus, by *Lagrange Multiplier Theorem*, using the 4th constraint, we get that $f$ is maximized when $a^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3k$ , i.e. $~x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = \frac{a^2}{3}$ .

Therefore, $f$ is maximized when $~(x,y,z) = \left(\pm\dfrac{| a |}{3} , \pm\dfrac{| a |}{3} , \pm\dfrac{| a |}{3} \right)$ , and the maximum value of will be $\dfrac{a^6}{27}$ .

---

In fact, you don't need a strong result like Lagrange Multiplier in order to solve this problem. Observe that by simple AM-GM Inequality, we have : $$(xyz)^2 = x^2\cdot y^2 \cdot z^2 \leqslant \left[\dfrac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{3}\right]^3 = \left(\dfrac{a^2}{3}\right)^3 = \dfrac{a^6}{27}$$ and the maximum is attained when $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = \dfrac{a^2}{3}$ , which is certainly same as the result produced using Lagrange Multiplier. Hope it helps.